# How to get the address which locked the fund on a smart contract?

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli, smart-contract, script

I have two users. The first user locks 1 ADA with a Datum at a script address. The second one unlocks the 1 ADA with the same Datum and should now send 5 ADA to user one.

Can I now implement a logic in my endpoints so that the second user can send 5 ADA directly to the first user. In order to do that the second user needs two know the wallet address of the first user, but how does he get this information?

Thanks!